# Understanding conditional statements in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to understand some statements of existing reactjs code

```
<Modal.Footer>
    { getButtons.call(this)}
    { this.props.footerLinkText && getFooterLink.call(this) }
</Modal.Footer>
```

**How will this be evaluated?**

```
this.props.footerLinkText && getFooterLink.call(this)
```

I understand it is a condition?

**Also this code:**

```
function cancelBtn() {
    return (
        <Form.Btn type={ this.props.closeBtnType || 'secondary-outline' }
                  size={ this.props.closeBtnSize || 'lg' }
                  key="cancelBtn"
                  onClick={ this.props.closeBtnAction ? this.doCloseAction.bind(this) : this.close.bind(this) }
        >{ this.props.closeBtnText || 'Cancel' }</Form.Btn>
    );
}
```

Not sure. Just need quick explanation.

Comment: You really ought to [vote on the answers and accept one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> { this.props.footerLinkText && getFooterLink.call(this) }

This is a [Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). It means that if `this.props.footerLinkText` is true, `getFooterLink` will be executed.

> { this.props.closeBtnText || 'Cancel' }

if `this.props.closeBtnText` is truthy, `Cancel` is returned. As a result, `Cancel` will be displayed

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Exactly i was looking for.

Comment: Your explanation "if `this.props.closeBtnText` is not true…" is incomplete or slightly misleading. As an 'OR' operator, if `this.props.closeBtnText` is true it will return its value *or* it will return 'Cancel'.

Answer (score 1):

### Binary and Ternary operators

What you see in the first example is a binary short-circuit evaluation expression using the logical 'AND' operator `&&`. *See: [Logical Operators - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)*

In the second example, you have a series of binary short-circuit evaluation expressions using the logical 'OR' operator `||`, followed by a conditional evaluation using the ternary operator `?` `:`. *See: [Conditional (ternary) Operator - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)*

Neither of these is native to ReactJS, but they are well suited to use in JSX because they are expressions that can be evaluated "inline", whereas statements like `if`-`else` do not work unless placed inside of an *[immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)* or moved out of the JSX markup. *See: [If-Else in JSX | React](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html)*

*See also:*

- *[Expressions and operators - JavaScript |
  MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)*
- *[Ben Alman » Immediately-Invoked Function Expression
  (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Exactly i was looking for.

Comment: @VJV I'm glad to hear it. Welcome, to StackOverflow BTW. Now, [you know what to do](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). ;)